# How to use Multiple font in TextInput in kivy?

Tags: python, android, fonts, kivy, font-family

I am creating a Email Aap using kivy.
While the user writes a Email, one can use multiple languages in a single Mail. But no font contains all locales.So, is there a way
to use mutiple fonts in TextInput?

Comment: You can choose the appropriate font depending on the system language, and of course there are universal fonts, but they weigh a lot

Comment: In that case, is it possible to use multiple fonts at a time.